# Problem with passing variables between two php files

Tags: php

I am following an online tutorial on php and i'm having a problem. I have no idea what could be the problem

```
<h1>Order Online!</h1>
<form action="order.php" method="POST"> 
    Bread (0.99 USD): 
    <input type="text" name="bread" />  
        <br /><br />
    Cookie (1.29 USD): 
    <input type="text" name="cookie" />
        <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit order" />
</form>
```

This file is supposed to take two numbers (yes I know that the inputs should be type="number") and send them to order.php

```
<?php 
 
$bread = $_POST['bread'];
$cookie = $_POST['cookie']; 
$sum = 0.99 * $bread + 1.29 * $cookie;

echo<<<END

<h2>Order Summary</h2>

<table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>Bread (0.99 USD)</td> <td>$bread</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cookie (1.29 USD)</td> <td>$Cookie</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Total</td> <td>$sum USD</td>
</tr>   
</table>

END;

?>
```

In the video everything was working perfectly, meanwhile everytime i try it, it results with
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjE3O.png):

Earlier today I was able to run a php file perfectly fine, and now i have been stuck with this problem.

Comment: Remove echo part

Comment: Have you installed the PHP interpreter? You can't run PHP code in a browser.

Comment: BTW, the syntax choice and total lack of escaping or validation suggests it isn't a good tutorial.